# Property value within @Scheduled annotation

Tags: spring-boot

I am currently using Spring-Boot 2.7.7 and have the following annotation:

```
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = "${scheduler.pollingInterval}", timeUnit = TimeUnit.MINUTES)
```

I want to set the rate from application.properties file, but get the error message:

```
Incompatible types. Found: 'java.lang.String', required: 'long'
```

How can I convert the value from String to long?
I already tried "#{${scheduler.pollingInterval}}" but with the same result.

Thanks and Best Regards
Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use fixedRateString instead of fixedRate.

```java
@Scheduled(fixedRateString = "${scheduler.pollingInterval}", timeUnit = TimeUnit.MINUTES)
```

Comment: Yes so simple should have looked at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
"#{new Long('${scheduler.pollingInterval}')}"
```

Comment: I think, it's a compiler error... (We cannot use string at all..for fixedRate)

Comment: Yes the same error, this will work for normal class properties but not within this annotation. And since you cannot refer to it from within the annotation it will not work. But there is a method that accepts string for the rate so the problem is solved. Thanks.